# Django dynamic verbose name

Tags: django, django-views

I'm struggling to think about how to achieve this. What I want to do is have a series of questions (to represent a Likert table) in a CharField object like so:

```
for a in range(1, 11):
    locals()['ATL' + str(a)] = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        choices=[
            [1, 'Disagree Completely'],
            [2, 'Disagree Strongly'],
            [3, 'Disagree'],
            [4, 'Neutral'],
            [5, 'Agree'],
            [5, 'Agree Strongly'],
            [7, 'Agree Completely'],
        ],
        widget=widgets.RadioSelectHorizontal(),
        verbose_name = Constants.ATL_qu_list[a-1])
del a
```

And then change the verbose name for the question depending on the question number (again, I know I'm not supposed to be using locals() to store variables). Is there an easier way of achieving a dynamic label though? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve here. A model field represents a database column, they can't be dynamic. And they are defined as attributes of a model class, not local variables. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think I've found an answer to my own question. What I wanted to do was dynamically declare different CharFields with different labels depending on the question. Given all Likert questionnaires are seven point scales, I figured it was bad coding to declare each CharField separately when the functionality is pretty much the same for all of them. So what I wanted to do was to develop a system where I would only have to declare the Likert CharField once, and then apply a different label to each of them depending on the question being asked. I'll elaborate in further detail below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my answer (as well as a clarification for what I am looking for). Basically I had a series of Likert questions to put to participants which I wanted to represent as CharFields. Because each Likert question uses the same seven choice scale, it seems like inefficient coding to repeat the same functionality and only change the verbose name between each declaration.

Accordingly, I've instead used this method to achieve what I want:

```
# Reads in the list of survey questions
with open('survey/survey_questions.csv') as csvfile:
data_read = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
... 
for a in range(1, 11):
    locals()['ATL' + str(a)] = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        choices=[
            [1, 'Disagree Completely'],
            [2, 'Disagree Strongly'],
            [3, 'Disagree'],
            [4, 'Neutral'],
            [5, 'Agree'],
            [6, 'Agree Strongly'],
            [7, 'Agree Completely'],
        ],
        widget=widgets.RadioSelectHorizontal(),
        verbose_name = data_read[a-1][0])
 del a
```